# Django filter by field in same model

Tags: django

I need to get a filtered list from a field compartison in the same model:

```
class Code(models.Model):
     now = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
     setpoint = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I've tried:

```
from django.db.models import F
ConversationReply.objects.annotate(pass=F(now)).filter(setpoint=pass)
```

Is there a way to get:

```
 Code.objects.filter( now__lte=setpoint )
```

the result should by the queryset where the current value stored in now is lower than the setpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
Code.objects.filter(now__lte=F('setpoint'))
```

See the docs [referencing fields in the model with filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) for more info.